# IOS расшарить VK

Tags: ios, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, cocoa

Доброго времени суток! Хотелось бы узнать, как я могу расшарить в вк, без SDK.
Ну т.е. хотелось бы узнать ссылку, типа:

```
vk://vk.com/...
```

И вызвать по такому типу

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"vk://vk.com/ХХХ"]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Может кто-то что-то делал подобное?

Comment: весь vk api задокументирован, можно, все что вам надо там посмотреть. более того vk ios sdk весь сурс лежит на гите - можете прямо оттуда копипастить все, что вам надо. Ну и напоминание: чтоб расшарить, надо сначала залогиниться и получить токен. Другими словами это достаточно большой велосипед, чтобы его самому изобретать

Answer (score 0):

Отдайте это в руки системы

```
func shareText(text: String) {
    var shareItems = [AnyObject]()
    shareItems.append(text  as AnyObject)

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
        UIActivityType.print,
        UIActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
        UIActivityType.postToFlickr,
        UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
        UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
        UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard
    ]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```